# Allowing named elements in a multi-content custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

**Requirement**

Let's start with what I am trying to achieve. I want to have a grid with 2 columns and a grid splitter (there is a little more to it that that, but let's keep it simple). I want to be able to use this grid in a lot of different places, so instead of creating it each time I want to make a custom control that contain two `ContentPresenters`.

The end goal is effectively to be able to write XAML like this:

```
<MyControls:MyGrid>
    <MyControls:MyGrid.Left>
        <Label x:Name="MyLabel">Something unimportant</Label>
    </MyControls:MyGrid.Left>
    <MyControls:MyGrid.Right>
        <Label>Whatever</Label>
    </MyControls:MyGrid.Right>
</MyControls:MyGrid>
```

IMPORTANT: Notice that I want to apply a `Name` to my `Label` element.

**Attempt 1**

I did a lot of searching for solutions, and the best way I found was to create a `UserControl` along with a XAML file that defined my grid. This XAML file contained the 2 `ContentPresenter` elements, and with the magic of binding I was able to get something working which was great. However, the problem with that approach is not being able to `Name` the nested controls, which results in the following build error:

> Cannot set Name attribute value 'MyName' on element 'MyGrid'. 'MyGrid'
>   is under the scope of element 'MyControls', which already had a name
>   registered when it was defined in another scope.

With that error in hand, I went back to Dr. Google...

**Attempt 2 (current)**

After a lot more searching I found some information here on SO that suggested the problem was due to having an associated XAML file with the `MyGrid` class, and the problem should be solvable by removing the XAML and creating all the controls via code in the `OnInitialized` method.

So I headed off down that path and got it all coded and compiling. The good news is that I can now add a `Name` to my nested `Label` control, the bad news is **nothing renders**! Not in design mode, and not when running the application. No errors are thrown either.

So, my question is: What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

I am also open to suggestions for other ways to meet my requirements.

**Current code**

```
public class MyGrid : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Left", typeof(object), typeof(MyGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object Left
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(LeftProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LeftProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Right", typeof(object), typeof(MyGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object Right
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(RightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RightProperty, value); }
    }

    Grid MainGrid;

    static MyGrid()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyGrid)));
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);

        //Create control elements
        MainGrid = new Grid();

        //add column definitions
        ColumnDefinition leftColumn = new ColumnDefinition()
        {
            Name = "LeftColumn",
            Width = new GridLength(300)
        };
        MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(leftColumn);

        MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
        {
            Width = GridLength.Auto
        });

        //add grids and splitter
        Grid leftGrid = new Grid();
        Grid.SetColumn(leftGrid, 0);
        MainGrid.Children.Add(leftGrid);

        GridSplitter splitter = new GridSplitter()
        {
            Name = "Splitter",
            Width = 5,
            BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 170, 170, 170)),
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 0, 1, 0)
        };
        MainGrid.Children.Add(splitter);

        Grid rightGrid = new Grid();
        Grid.SetColumn(rightGrid, 1);
        MainGrid.Children.Add(rightGrid);

        //add content presenters
        ContentPresenter leftContent = new ContentPresenter();
        leftContent.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding("Left") { Source = this });
        leftGrid.Children.Add(leftContent);

        ContentPresenter rightContent = new ContentPresenter();
        rightContent.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding("Right") { Source = this });
        rightGrid.Children.Add(rightContent);

        //Set this content of this user control
        this.Content = MainGrid;
    }
}
```

Comment: `creating all the controls via code` - Wrong. That's what `ControlTemplate`s are for.

Comment: @HighCore: Thanks for your helpful comment... are you saying you have a suggestion to replace my second attempt?

Comment: You should switch the implementation from `UserControl` to `CustomControl` and there should be no `Name` problems.

Comment: Look, I have done all sorts of `UserControl`s and `Custom Control`s and I never faced this issue. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @HighCore: Yes, obviously something is wrong, that is why I am asking here, so I can find out exactly what is wrong, or find a better solution. Do you have something useful to contribute to that?

Comment: @NovitchiS: Do you mean a `Control`? As in a class that doesn't have a dedicated XAML file? I tried this already, where I defined the control within `Generic.xaml` and it didn't work. Or do you mean another way? I can give it another try now though

Comment: @NovitchiS: I remember the problem with `CustomControl` now. I needed to be able to add an event to the splitter and reference each grid column within that event. This did not seem to work when the control was defined in `generic.xaml`, that is why I gave up on that approach

Comment: You should find a good example of a CustomControl. You can find the splitter using `GetTemplateChild` method and add any event you like. You should do this in an override for `OnApplyTemplate` method of your control.

Comment: You can read about the issue here: http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2007/06/21/building-a-control-which-holds-content-customcontrol-vs-markupsubclassing-vs-usercontrol/

Comment: @NovitchiS: Do you happen to have a link or a decent CustomControl example? I am just trying your suggestion now, and forgetting about the event stuff, I am having problems with binding content to the ContentProvider, as in it just doesn't bind. Should I create these binding in the `OnApplyTemplate` method too?

Comment: The [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, might help.

Comment: @NovitchiS: Thanks for your help, I have managed to get it working using a CustomControl. Your suggestion to use `OnApplyTemplate` was the thing that has enabled me to get this approach working. Feel free to add an answer, though I indent to add my own detailed answers explaining it fully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some discussion via comments, it quickly became clear that neither of my attempted solutions was the correct way to go about it. So I set out on a third adventure hoping this one would be the final solution... and it seems it is!

---

**Disclaimer**: I do not yet have enough experience with WPF to confidently say that my solution is the best and/or recommended way to do this, only that it definitely works.

---

First of all create a new custom control: `"Add" > "New Item" > "Custom Control (WPF)"`. This will create a new class that inherits from `Control`.

In here we put our dependency properties for bind to out content presenters:

```
public class MyGrid : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Left", typeof(object), typeof(MyGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object Left
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(LeftProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LeftProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Right", typeof(object), typeof(MyGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object Right
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(RightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RightProperty, value); }
    }

    static MyGrid()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyGrid)));
    }
}
```

When you add this class file in Visual Studio, it will automatically create a new "Generic.xaml" file in the project containing a Style for this control, along with a Control Template within that style - this is where we define our control elements...

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControls:MyGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyControls:MyGrid}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="500" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="LeftContent" />
                    </Grid>
                    <GridSplitter Width="5" BorderBrush="#FFAAAAAA" BorderThickness="1,0,1,0">
                    </GridSplitter>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="RightContent" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The final step is to hook up the bindings for the 2 content presenters, so back to the class file.

Add the following override method to the `MyGrid` class:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    //Apply bindings and events
    ContentPresenter leftContent = GetTemplateChild("LeftContent") as ContentPresenter;
    leftContent.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding("Left") { Source = this });

    ContentPresenter rightContent = GetTemplateChild("RightContent") as ContentPresenter;
    rightContent.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding("Right") { Source = this });
}
```

And that's it! The control can now be used in other XAML code like so:

```
<MyControls:MyGrid>
    <MyControls:MyGrid.Left>
        <Label x:Name="MyLabel">Something unimportant</Label>
    </MyControls:MyGrid.Left>
    <MyControls:MyGrid.Right>
        <Label>Whatever</Label>
    </MyControls:MyGrid.Right>
</MyControls:MyGrid>
```

---

**Thanks** to @NovitchiS for your input, your suggestions were vital in getting this approach to work